# To map topic to a document after topic modeling is done with LDA

Tags: lda, gensim

Is there any way I can map generated topic from LDA to the list of documents and identify to which topic it belongs to ? I am interested in clustering documents using unsupervised learning and segregating it into appropriate cluster. Any link, code example, paper will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Data Science SE! Please explain your question further, it is currently unclear.

Comment: @RomainReboulleau Hi Romain, Thanks!!. Ok. This is the case that I try to do. For example, 1) I have 5 Topic words from 20 new groups data set after run LDA modeling using the Gensim package. The 5 Topics words are #1 Game, #2 Bible, #3 chemical, #5 sport. 2) I have new sentence. " I like to play video game using Playstation." 3) Here is my question. How I can map topic to a my sentence - " I like to play video game using Playstation." to "Topic #1 Game"